# what permissions does a user require to query AD from SQL Server?

Tags: active-directory, sql

Have created a linked server to active directory from SQL Server but getting a permission denied error when I try to query anything.

Under the security options for the linked server I have specified the connection to use a domain account which can query AD from powershell.

Should this account have any special permissions?

EDIT:

This is the error message I'm receiving from SQL

> The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported
>   an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the
>   permission to perform the operation.

Comment: What are you querying? Any user should be able to see accounts, but they can't necessarily see all of the attributes.

Comment: simply searching for account names...

Comment: Unless you actually have a server named "ADSI" I suspect your real issue may be a faulty query.

Comment: @John, I'm fairly sure that ADSI is a special case - so there doesn't need to be a server named ADSI for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered using Powershell, unless changed, normal, authenticated, non-admin user accounts have the right to search & Read AD.  No reason to believe this would be different from a SQL server.  Sounds like there is a config issue with the SQL or script.